# How to connect a database with a mobile application?

Tags: database, java-me

I want to make an application in j2me so that it interacts with database and keeps updating it. How can i connect my mobile application to the pc which has the database? Will it be through bluetooth or through Internet? Also the application needs to validate the login information provided by the user with the database and send back a query appropriately. How to accomplish this?And i want to connect to nokia phones and not windows mobile..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is upto you if you want to connect via Bluetooth or Internet.

Probably what you are trying to do is accessing a remote database from your Mobile device (j2me) using JDBC or similar tool.
Unfortunately, if you use CLDC then there is no tool for connecting to database using JDBC like tool, you need to do it manually i.e you need to send customized data like username, password from the MIDlet to Servlet and then the servlet deals with the database.

It is not necessary to use Servlet (i.e Java) in server side, you can use any other server-side language like PHP etc.

Here is an [example](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html)